# Find and remove <script> element with empty src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Facebook Plugin for wordpress has an issue where it adds a script element to the DOM with an empty src attribute.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3c-validation-error-caused-my-empty-src-tag-generated-by-plugin?replies=3

```
<script type='text/javascript' src=''></script>
```

The link above suggests editing core WP files.. 
Question is, would there be a way to find and remove using jQuery?

Something like below, which didn't work in locating the empty src / script element.

```
$('footer script').each(function(){ 
        if($(this).attr('src') == 'undefined' && $(this).length < 1){
            $(this).remove();  
        } 
     })
```

---

Edit : Since asking this question i've come to realise i need to remove the script element using PHP, in order for the page to validate.

Comment: It would also need to determine a script element without contents, as well as no src attribute.

Comment: ....what is your question? You have code, have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: How would that help?  This script would run after the page has been parsed and thus failed to validate.  Also, the src is not going to be blank, it'll be the URL of the directory containing the current page.

Comment: The `src` certainly won't be the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: @squit it was when i tested it

Comment: @Cam: It was the `"undefiend"` string? Or it was the `undefined` value? More likely the value.

Comment: What you should do is find the approriate `wp_enque_script` function in the plugin, and remove it. Not remove the faulty PHP code with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
$('footer script').each(function(){ 
    if(!$(this).attr("src")){
        $(this).remove();  
    } 
 });
```

This will remove every script tag with an empty src. This won't prevent the validation from failing, however.

Comment: thanks Sébastien for the constructive feedback. So needs to happen using PHP?

Comment: It needs to happen in PHP in one way or another. Sorry to bring the bad news, but if you want to W3-validate, you'll need to go through the plug-ins. The good news is, if it uses a hook, kill it by overriding the hook.

Comment: @squint: Thank you. Changed accordingly.

Comment: Could the downvoter stop being a coward and actually mention *why* they've downvoted? Also, edited code.

Comment: Your if statement will never be true. The src cant be truthy (have a length greater than 0) and have a 0 length.

Comment: @Ian: Looks like we've hit a telepathy moment there.

Comment: thanks again, this answered the original Q, 'would there be a way to find and remove using jQuery?'.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the solution of Sébastien. I only needed to find the script tags with empty src and do something different with them (copy data-src to src for a privacy guard, where src will be set if consent was given), but removing also works.

```
$('footer script[src=""]').each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

FWIW: To set src by data-src looks like:

```
$(this).find('script[src=""]').each(function () {
    var src = $(this).data('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src).show();
});
```

Works also with iframe by replacing script with iframe.